# Local storage lost after redirect

Tags: angular, https

I have an angular app running on https. This app redirects to an external website for login and provides the return URL to this external website so the external system can call my app again after successfull authentication.

Unfortunately my local storage is no longer there when the external system calls my return URL again.

This behaviour only seems to happen since I moved my system into the cloud and on https. As long I was running everything locally and had no https it worked all fine.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

Adding the piece of code which is doing the redirect:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions){ 
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
    private handleError(error: any) {
    if (error.status === 401) {
       window.location.href= "https://externalsystem/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=https://myapp.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/login/SFDC&state="+window.location.href;
    }

    return Observable.throw(error._body);
    }
}
```

As you see I do a redirect to the external system if my backend comes back with an authentication error. I call the external system, provide a return URL to my system.

When my return URL is call the local/session storage is gone.

Rgds
Michael

Comment: use session storage

Comment: Ideally, nothing like this should be happening. Can u post relevant amount of code for us to have alook ?

Comment: changed to session storage - no difference.

Comment: Added the relevant code